# IPython's history-search-backward not working as desired

Tags: ipython, readline

IPython's `history-search-backward` feature is one of my favorite features. `history-search-backward` allows you to type part of a command and then search backward through your readline history for commands that began with that part of the command. By default (I believe) these are bound to `UpArrow` or `Ctrl`+`P` and `DownArrow` or `Ctrl`+`N` (for backward and forward respectively).

They are not working for me. Instead they just go linearly through my history instead of taking into account the characters I've already typed to (allgedly) filter my history.

I'm running IPython 0.13.2 (with Python 2 and 3) on Arch Linux from within XTerm.

If I hit `Escape`, `Ctrl`+`P`, then `UpArrow` and `DownArrow` work exactly as I want them to.

Additionally if I change my `ipython_config.py` to include

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.readline_parse_and_bind = ['"\\e[B": history-search-forward', '"\\e[A": history-search-backward']
```

then I can just do `Escape` `UpArrow` for the desired behaviour. ([Here's the rest of my config file](https://github.com/0xtobit/.files/blob/master/ipython_config.py).)

`Ctrl`+`V` `UpArrow` produces `^[[A` as I expect. I have the python `readline` library installed (which seems to fix common problems with macs running IPython).

I have these lines in my `.bashrc`

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

and they work exactly as I want them to within `bash`.

I have no idea what else to try next, so I've come here. Please help, I hope I've included enough information and done enough research.

Comment: You may want to check your `.inputrc` file as well - that could be affecting it.

Comment: Okay, my `.inputrc` just has
`set editing-mode vi` and 
`set keymap vi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was `set keymap vi` set in my `.inputrc`. I removed that and IPython history went back to what I expected. Thanks to [@Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k)!