# IPython's partial up-arrow search not working; Ctrl-P is fine

Tags: ipython

Our sysadmin recently updated us to OpenSUSE Leap 42.1.  I immediately noticed that IPython's history search behaviour changed.  Previously, if I typed part of a command then pressed `Up`, I could scroll through those commands in the history matching the part that I'd entered.  This no longer works: `Up` just scrolls through the history one line at a time.

Using `Ctrl-P` to do the same thing still works perfectly but I'd like to restore that behaviour to `Up` if possible.

I didn't have a `~/.inputrc` file, and I tried creating one with the contents

```
# arrow up
"\e[A":history-search-backward
# arrow down
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

but that only added similar behavior to bash. Also, it means the `~/.inputrc` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350245/ipythons-history-search-backward-not-working-as-desired) doesn't work.

I'm using IPython version 3.2.2 and Python 2.7.9, if relevant. The Python `readline` package appears to be installed but I don't know what the install order was.

Comment: You might want to check in `/etc/inputrc` as well, though I don't know if that actually affects it.